Verify at compile time that the length of an array is equal to a counter's value
I've defined a function that generates a struct (whose fields I've defined elsewhere). In addition to setting some of the fields based on inputs to the function, the function also assigns an int to the output struct as one of the field values. Something like the following:
int counter = 0;
myStruct struct_generator(u_int8_t foo, u_int16_t bar){
    return myStruct{
        .val1 = foo,
        .val2 = bar,
        .val3 = counter++
    };
}

I will call this function many times to create many structs, each with its unique val3 value. Something like the following, where I just chose 6 calls as an example:
// counter == 0
myStruct str1 = struct_generator(1,2);  // counter == 1
myStruct str2 = struct_generator(1,3);  // counter == 2
...
myStruct str6 = struct_generator(5,42);  // counter == 6

Then, after the last such struct has been created, I make an array of the addresses of all the structs using a templated variadic function, which I'll call make_ptr_array(), which would be used like this:
auto all_myStruct_pointers = make_ptr_array(&str1, &str2, &str3, &str4, &str5, &str6);

And essentially, I want to do a compile-time check that the length of all_myStruct_pointers is equal to counter. I've tried
static_assert(all_myStruct_pointers.size() == counter, "Wrong length bucko");

but this does not work. I get the compiler error the value of ‘counter’ is not usable in a constant expression. Making a constexpr equal to counter doesn't solve this either. The following does work:
static_assert(all_myStruct_pointers.size() == 6, "Wrong length bucko");

but this isn't a solution because it of course doesn't update automatically whenever I decide to, for instance, create str7 and str8 down the road...
I'm looking for a solution that gives me a compile-time error whenever the array I create doesn't have length equal to an int--an int that is not hard-coded but is known by the time the array will have been created. I thought this would be simpler, but so far it's been a major headache.

"I will call this function many times to create many structs..." Technically you're not generating "structs" but objects of that type. You need to correct the terminology.

Due to a regrettable dearth of time machines, a compiler cannot check at compile time a number that'll only become known at runtime.

In short, you cannot compare a compile time quantity with a runtime quantity.

Since you're incrementing counter after creation of each variable, counter cannot be constexpr by definition.

Why not just make an array of objects to begin with? std::array all_myStruct = {struct_generator(1,2), struct_generator(1,3), ..., struct_generator(5,42)}

@NathanOliver OP says "doesn't update automatically whenever I decide to, for instance, create str7 and str8 down the road...". Using std::array looks like the obvious choice here.

@user12002570 do they mean down the road like later versions of code or later on in the code base?  They can't change the size of all_myStruct_pointers after the first time either so I'm not sure what they mean by that.

Personally I you just stick with a vector and add and remove objects ass needed.  All of this code besides the array happens at run time so you don't gain much.

@NathanOliver My understanding(from reading the question) is that they are talking about "later in the code base".

"I'm looking for a solution that gives me a compile-time error whenever the array I create doesn't have length equal to an int--an int that is not hard-coded but is known by the time the array will have been created.". You do know the difference between compile-time and runtime, right? int counter = 0; this is not code that can be evaluated at compile-time. There is no solution for what you're asking. The only way to do that is to check at runtime. Don't waste time searching for hacks or workarounds for this, it's not worth it. Just do it the way it's supposed to be done.
